# Find if more rows exist based on two columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following sheet:

[image]

My VBA code loops through the rows and now I need to find out if there is another line with the same column A (customer ID) and G (day of week).
Row 2596 and 2863 is both on Saturday but on different times (column H).
The formula in I3205 is sumproduct to find the time 12:05 because it looks at one row below and down only.
The issue is when there are no other duplicates as I3206 displays. The formula in that cell is from row 2864 (one line below the last one, `=SUMPRODUCT((A2864:A3200=2193)*(G2864:G3200="Lördag")*H2864:H3200)`) and it returns 0.
I could live with that but the issue is that 0 is also the same as 00:00, although it's not an issue now I would rather not have it return 0 but rather some error or something else that I know means no match.

What kind of other formulas can I use to get the matching time in H when it exists but also an error or something that I know for sure is not a time when there is nothing found?

The answer can either be a VBA code or a formula, I only displayed it on the sheet since that is easier than a VBA equivalent worksheetformula.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question.  Does countifs or sumifs give you what you need?

Comment: If I use sumifs I still get 0 returned on `=SUMIFS(H2864:H3200;A2864:A3200;2193;G2864:G3200;"Lördag")`, I don't want to get 0 returned since that can be misinterpreted as the time 00:00. And countifs also give 0.

Comment: `IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"c",$B$1:$B$5,3)>0,SUMIFS($C$1:$C$5,A1:A5,"c",$B$1:$B$5,3),"None")`

Comment: But that is just band aid. What if the time in column H is 00:00, then your formula will give me None.

Comment: What do you want it to say?

Comment: If there is nothing found: something else than 0. If something is found the time in column H.

Comment: `IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"c",$B$1:$B$5,3)>0,SUMIFS($C$1:$C$5,A1:A5,"c",$B$1:$B$5,3),NA())`  Not sure i understand what you mean>???

Comment: Oh.. I see my error now. I thought your formula was if(SUMIFS()>=;SUMIFS(). I misread what you wrote. You are correct! Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check using COUNTIFS then use SUMIFS, like so

`IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"c",$B$1:$B$5,3)>0,SUMIFS($C$1:$C$5,A1:A5,"c",$B$1:$B$5,3),NA())`

The #N/A error will be generated if none found.